# Cell with multiple color formatting results only to first color being applied

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

If a Google Sheet cell has 2 Conditional formattings, one which changes only font color, one which changes only the background, only the first conditional formatting affects the cell.

The reason might be because when the color is set to `NONE`, it is not interpreted as transparent.

When I set a font or background color to `NONE`, it should be transparent, so other conditions could affect the transparent part.

Demo sheet attached:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFX8PBlKEJszK3MotTompP9OufD4OrMUrOz8E-mC5jk/edit?usp=sharing

An idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will never get a blue background with **`=C4>1`**. you have to change it to **`=C4>0`** or **`=C4=1`**

Conditional formatting rules are priority based and if one rule is applied the other rules just skip it. To resolve it you will need to add one more rule with: **`=AND(C4>0;B4>0)`**

[image: 0]

Comment: Almost good. True, but can not change the order of the format rules. So I need other solution to avoid deleting old rules (rule change still allowed).

Comment: you can just clone them down by one and then edit the first one and delete rest of the clones

Comment: I found a drag&drop panel to change the order at least in webbrowser. But how to clone them?

Comment: yup, drag&drop is also an option...

Comment: cloning is basically done by clicking on CF rule to edit it but instead of any edit you click on **+Add another rule** and then click on **Done**

Comment: Thank you for your answer!