Google Sheets Conditional Formatting not working: just the first applying rule is executed
My conditional formatting rule does not affect the cells even though it should.
(Even if no rules whose range covers the cell modify the same properties of the cell, but, e.g., one sets "bold" and one modifies the background color.)
Keywords: Google Sheets: conditional formatting is not working, conditional formatting does not work.


The cell is not formatted as a number (but, e.g., as a string).

The cell is not within the range of the rule.

No formatting is set for the rule.

The condition does not return "TRUE" (but "FALSE" or something completely else; i.e., either your condition/formula is incorrect or the cell should not return "TRUE").


Recall that your own formula (if any) should be written so that it suits the top-left cell of your range.

Google Sheets only applies the first conditional formatting rule that returns TRUE and ignores the rest.

This is why you may think your rule does not work when there is another conditional formatting rule whose range contains the same cell (and happens to be TRUE).
Solution: before the rules A->X and B->Y, add the rule A&B->X&Y. Then X happens iff A is true, and Y happens iff Z is true.
From the left end of the rule you can move the rule.
The following is a better answer but hard to find before you know the reason for your rule not working: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126043
More information: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8277968/how-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-to-apply-to-the-row-and-column-of-a-cell-except-for-itself?hl=en
